# Simple Ping Tool Failing

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, scripts, ping

I am trying to apply what I learned about shell scripting to a ping tool, but I can't seem to work out what I'm doing wrong.

I want my ping tool to contain a prompt that creates a variable for the target site and packet count, so that it is reusable, and doesn't default to sending continuous packets to the target URL.

My current script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The....."
figlet -f banner "Pinger"
echo " "
read -p "[*] Enter the target host:   " $TGT
read -p "[*] Enter number of packets to send:   " $PKT
ping -c$PKT $TGT
exit0
```

This script does not pick up the integer for the nmap -c flag.

I have attempted to debug the problem in the following ways:

`ping $TGT` works perfectly on it's own.

`ping -c{$PKT}` doesn't execute.

`ping -c $PKT` and `ping -c {$PKT}` also, do not execute properly.

The error shown is:

```
ping: option requires an arguement -- 'c'
```

Can someone tell me what the fix is so I can understand the context for basic variable usage?

Comment: `read` usage is `read -p 'prompt: ' var` not `read -p 'prompt: ' $var`

Comment: @steeldriver whatever is within the quotes becomes a part of the prompt. The space was intentional, as it looks better for the user as host:.......<input> as a pose to host:<input> all jumbled together with no spaces.

Comment: @tREEs I'm not referring to what's inside the quotes - it's the variable assignment that's the issue (`$TGT` should just be `TGT`)

Comment: That's an incredibly stupid rule. But you just fixed my problem, and for that, you're a legend. Thankyou @steeldriver

Comment: @tREEs It's by design. Any mention of a variable with a dollar sign at the start refers to its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I'm ignoring lines 2-4 of the script since they're irrelevant.

When using `read`, you need to give it a variable **name** (`TGT`). Using a dollar sign (`$TGT`) refers to the variable's **value**. In this case the value is null, so `read` defaults to the variable `REPLY`.

As well:

1. By convention, uppercase variable names are reserved for environment variables (e.g. `PATH`) and other special variables (e.g. `RANDOM`).
2. It's always better to use descriptive variable names, like for example `target` and `n_packets`
3. **Always quote variables.**
4. `exit0` is invalid, plus `exit 0` will mask any errors that happen near the end of the script, plus `exit` is implicit, so don't even bother writing it.
5. NBD in this case, but using `read -r` is a good habit.

So in the end:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "[*] Enter the target host:   " target
read -rp "[*] Enter number of packets to send:   " n_packets
ping -c "$n_packets" "$target"
```

Lastly, [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is very handy for debugging shell scripts in the future. I ran your script through it and got most of the above points.

Regarding the syntax you tried, `{$PKT}`, I think you were confused with `${PKT}`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation and clarification on readability. I'll be sure to save the website, looks great! I also removed my theory questions from the question regarding the coding issue, as they were to help me expand on my understanding - something I had apparently none of.

Comment: @tREEs Welcome! We all have to start somewhere. I removed the mention of theory questions, and also added two minor points I forgot before.